# Trying to disallow lateral and backward sprinting in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player in a world that can move around fine. When the player presses shift, the speed increases. I have a way to check for sprint, but the `if` that I've used doesn't seem to work. The player can sprint in any direction.

```
void CheckForSprint()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && !Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && !Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && !Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        speed = 6;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        speed = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem; is the player only allowed to sprint when ONLY holding down W?

Comment: You'll probably want to include the code where you're using speed as well. It'll probably make more sense to change speed as you use it, rather than modifying it within another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code you added in your question.

You mention the keys "A", "S" and "D", but you don't include "W". I believe you try to move the character at speed 6 in case the player press `LeftShift` (Probably your run button) and `W`, but ignores the `LeftShift` in case it is moving to the left, right or backwards (it will move then at speed 3 just).

If that is the case, and you want to move at speed 3 in case `W`, `S` OR `D` is pressed, what you should use is `Input.GetButton` instead of `GetButtonDown`. The reason:

- **GetButton**:   Returns true while the virtual button identified by buttonName is held down.
- **GetButtonDown**:   Returns true during the frame the user pressed down the virtual button identified by buttonName.

So GetButtonDown will return true only during the frame the user pressed down the key. But will ignore when holding. Check [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html)

So try to write the condition in this way instead:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
    speed = 6;
} else {
    speed = 3;
}
```